# JQuery.Ajax call with <> in string

Tags: jquery, ajax, string, inequality

I have a simple jquery ajax call to update data from an input box. The moment I have any markup in the input, Eg a `<div>` it does not make it to the controller. Any help please on how I call ajax and save to database texxt that has html code markups in it

```
$.ajax({
  type:post,
  url: "/dom/updatelement",
  data: "name="+name+&id="+id
});
```

Where `name` may contain markup.

Comment: If you have syntax highlighting you should see the syntax error in your code immediately...

Answer (score 5):

Here's the correct way to send data in a POST request:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: '/dom/updatelement',
  data: { name: name, id: id }
});
```

jQuery will ensure to properly url encode the data when using this syntax.

You could of course could have done this by hand using the [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) method:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: '/dom/updatelement',
  data: 'name=' + encodeURIComponent(name) + '&id=' + encodeURIComponent(id)
});
```

But honestly the first method seems kinda more readable and preferable.

Comment: Thanks, sorry, still struggling. As soon as I put < in the text, it does not go to the controller. Tried using encodeURIComponent, still doesn't go to the controller.

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET application? ASP.NET automatically blocks requests containing such characters. For example in ASP.NET MVC you could decorate the corresponding controller action with the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute to disable this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should make the correct Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/dom/updatelement",
    data: {
        name: name,
        id: id
    }
});
```

Next, you may transform characters like `<` or `>` in the controller part using special functions (e.g. [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) in PHP).

Comment: Sorry, not using PHP, using ASP.NET MVC 4, so can't try special characters. As soon as I add a < doesn't go to the controller.